# React Navigation redirect on redux store change in component

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux, native, react-navigation

I'm looking for a good solution for redux action based redirection, using [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation)

Current scenario:
In the App.js I initialise the redux store and render the Main.js component in it.
In the Main comp. I wait for the redux-persist's rehydrate to finish (and later on every sync actions to end too).
If it's finished, I render the Navigator comp..
(If it's possible I'd like to call the auth token checker action here and redirect based on a redux store value (isAuth). Right now I dont know how.)

The navigator first loads the LoginScreen comp. where I call the auth token action before the mount happens (cWillMount).
The problem is that I can't put the redirection code in a method which would re-run on reudx store change (e.g.: render).

Where should I put the redirection code to run when the store variable changes?

Comment: There are several guides on React and Auth handling. What have you tried this far, can you show your code?

Comment: The only significant thing I tried is what i wrote down. Unfortunately I can't show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, you can try integrating react-navigation to Redux. [Official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux#handling-the-hardware-back-button-in-android) and [this article](https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-navigation-with-complete-redux-state-management-tab-bar-and-multiple-navigators-ed30a69d9a4d) will help.
Managing everything in Redux is probably worth it as you can move your navigation logic into your reducers and actions.

For the case of the token, I assume that you have a token stored using AsyncStorage. 
[Here](https://github.com/ybolaris/react-native-redux-OAth2.0) you can find a sample project of mine where I only implement an OAth2.0 authorization flow.

I used a 'Splash' screen for loading the token from AsyncStorage. Then, depending on the result, the app navigates to either the 'Welcome' screen or to the 'Main' screen. From the 'Welcome' screen the users can redirect to a Login webview where the authorization happens.

I used Redux Thunk for handling side effects. I hope my implementation can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the example. As I run through the code, it will help me with my problem.